# How to use ggplot to plot the trend of four variables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set records the tumor size at four different time points (each row is one patient). I want to perform an analysis on this dataset to show that overall for all patients, the tumor size is decreasing after each time point.

What kind of analysis can I do? How should I use ggplot to visualize these data and show the trend? Many thanks!

```
SUBJECTID   Baseline    1   2   3

1001        88          78  30  14
1002        29          26  66  16
1003        50          64  54  46
1004        91          90  99  43
1005        98          109 60  42
1007        100         100     54
1008        45          49  47  32
1009        75          66  57  7
1010        60          52  20  3
1011        68          68  56  47
1012        78          84  56  57
1013        71          70  8   5
1015        79          50  11  3
1016        73          60  57  36
1017        54          27  16
1018        50          37  33  26
1019        115         68  33  67
1021        63          55  0   0
1022        98          91  76  75
1024        76          76      0
1025        47          45  42  42
1026        32          25  14  0
1027        40          37  65  
1028        60          110 110 0
```

Comment: Consider joining the data, resulting in columns with patient IDs and dates, then you can use date on x axis, tumor size on y, and facet by tumor type. You'll get a lot of lines, but will be able to tell a general trend. Also, dput() the dataset in your question so we can provide code with the data, pictures are hard to work with

Comment: The data has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [box plot](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html) might work. Try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(key = "time", value = "tumor_size", -SUBJECTID) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, tumor_size)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title = "Tumor Size ~ Time",
       subtitle = "Insert subtitle if you want",
       caption = "Insert caption if you want",
       x = "Time",
       y = "Tumor Size (insert unit)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(family = "Palatino"),
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20)
  )
```

[image]

You could also add `geom_jitter()` if you'd like. After the `geom_boxplot() +` line, add:

```
geom_jitter(width = 0.1, pch = 21, fill = "grey") +
```

You'll get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why after I run ggplot(aes(key, value)) line, df was changed to a list, then geom_boxplot() doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Hm, the `ggplot2` line shouldn't make a list. The second line `gather(key, value, -SUBJECTID)` is used to [gather](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) all the *time* variables into a single variable which is named `key`. In this way, we have a [tidy](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org) dataset where each column is a variable (i.e. `SUBJECTID`, `key`, and `value`), where `key` is time and `value` is tumor size. I should probably rename these to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

To show that overall tumor size is decreasing after each time point, you usually want a mean tumor size after each time frame. It's much easier to plot than every individual element. I've written how to do this using your first four rows, producing a dot graph:

```
baseline <- c(88, 29, 50, 91)
dAC <- c(78, 26, 64, 90)
InterReg <- c(30, 66, 54, 99)
PreSurg <- c(14, 16, 46, 43)
matrix <- rbind(baseline, dAC, InterReg, PreSurg)
means <- rowMeans(matrix)
plot(means)
```

**Dot graph:**

[image: Dot Graph]

In terms of what analysis to do, I can't really answer that. That depends on what you want it to look like. What I've done is the most basic way of representing the data. You may want to use a column graph, a bar graph, a line graph etc. That's up to your personal preference. In terms of using ggplot, here are many different examples you can use: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf